# 400–430 degrees Celsius heated bath

Tags: hydrocarbons, boiling-point, equipment

I want to perform a reaction which needs the temperature to be maintained between 400–430 °C. Since it's the only practical solution, I opted for a heated bath.

I'm looking for a hydrocarbon fraction/blend with the boiling point in this range, however, I keep finding conflicting information. If anyone knows such a hydrocarbon product please, let me know.

Comment: Those temperatures are well above the flash point of any hydrocarbon I can find, and above the _autoignition_ point of many. Might you be able to get by with a sand bath or tightly-regulated mantle instead?

Comment: The point of a heated bath is that the temperature, given sufficient heating, will be exactly the boiling point of the medium. Sand bath would offer no control over the temperature.

Comment: Also, to rig such a mantle on ones own would be no small feat. Not to mention being able to afford one.

Comment: Keep in mind there is also a variety of [molten salt baths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molten_salt); however, you'll need a thermocouple and protect the glassware as the majority of molten salts would etch the glass.

Comment: What's wrong with carrying out your reaction in a furnace?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it doesn't specifically need to be a hydrocarbon, zinc metal melts at 419.5 °C. Could you do an "ice bath" of zinc chunks in molten zinc, maintaining the melt right at its melting point?

Comment: I have to say this is an interesting idea. I'll give it a good thought.

Comment: In fact, if it works it will be a superior solution, since I won't lose the zinc to the atmosphere the same way I would lose the liquid. I'll let you know how it went. Thank you!

Comment: Woods metal can used for this  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood%27s_metal

Comment: Word of warning -- this idea just came to me out of the blue. I'm not a practitioner. I have no idea if a solid-liquid zinc bath is something that's routinely done; if not, there may be good reasons why not.

Answer (score 5):

You can try $\ce{C30}$ hydrocarbon, triacontane (CAS #: 638-68-6). It is a straight chain hydrocarbon with formula weight of $\pu{422.8 gmol^{-1}}$ ($n$-$\ce{C30H62}$). It is a solid at $\pu{25 ^{\circ}C}$ and [NIST Webbook](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C638686&Mask=4) reported its boiling point as $\pu{722.9 K}$ ($\approx\pu{450 ^{\circ}C}$) at $\pu{1 atm}$. More phase changing data can be found in [NIST Webbook] and following reference:

- J. S. Chickos, W. Hanshaw, “Vapor Pressures and Vaporization Enthalpies of the *n*-Alkanes from $\ce{C21}$ to $\ce{C30}$ at $\mathrm{T} = \pu{298.15 K})$ by Correlation Gas Chromatography,” *J. Chem. Eng. Data* **2004**, *49(1)*, 77–85 (DOI: 10.1021/je0301747).

Comment: The vapor pressure would be significant at 400C (a mere 50C below boiling point), even if it didn't start to carbonize. Those vapors probably would ignite.

Comment: @Kevin Kostlan: I know the risk. I was thinking about a salt bath to be honest with you. But OP insisted that "he's looking for a hydrocarbon fraction/blend with the boiling point in this range" and then this'd be the answer.